# Не получается преобразовать массив. Не работает json_deocde

Tags: php, json, decode

Ребята помогите, нужна помощь.
Есть данные

```
{"stat":"Сообщение успешно обработано","status":"OK","messageId":"123","messageResult":"Запрос обработан","messageDate":1558037969,"lastName":"Мяяя","firstName":"Vzzz","middleName":"Kkk","iin":"111222333444","birthdate":"16.11.1993","period":"6","table":[{"DATE_OPR":"2011-12-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"172755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"123","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123213","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-01-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"116755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-02-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-03-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"1231231232","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-04-01T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"117219.59999999998","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"111176.27599999998","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-05-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""}]}
```

Значений table может быть разное количество.
Пытаюсь преобразовать в массив json через json_decode, но всё время возвращает пусто.
Подскажите, как мне преобразовать эти данные в многомерный массив, где несколько table?
Спасибо

Comment: Надо оторвать руки тому, кто этот джейсон формирует. Других способов нет

Comment: Это Бюро кредитной отчётности ))) Им не получится оторвать.

Comment: Возможно, бюро возвращает корректные данные, а дальше ты уже уродуешь их сам. Бывают такие любители. В любом случае, *это* разбору не подлежит.

Comment: Любой джсон линтер покажет где ошибка.

Comment: @u_mulder а чего его показывать то, там кавычки в строках не экранированы. Но судя по тому, что тут частенько проскакивает код, где Json строят руками, без использования json_encode, то появление такой шляпы собственно не кажется странным

Comment: Приведённый Вами JSON не годен. Если Вы не можете повлиять на исходную структуру и можете с уверенностью сказать, что в будущем проблемы будут возникать только с узлом `F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME`, то тогда только "ручное" экранирование. Ищите узел `F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME`, далее получайте подстроку между двоеточием и запятой и экранируйте кавычки. Но это всё равно "китайский" вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Что-то наврал в коде - кавычка портится - поправлю позже
> Но сама идея алгоритма верно описана

1. Исправлять надо там, откуда кривые данные приходят, а не там, где данные требуется использовать.
2. Вот я прям уверен, что там не только кавычки не экранированы, но и все остальные символы.
3. Если хочется какой-то полуадекватный костыль:

   1. Экранируем все обратные слеши чтобы разбить последовательности \t на 2 символа.
   2. Пытаемся парсить как json.
   3. Получилось? Ура!
   4. Иначе заменяем последний символ на его юникодный код и возвращаемся к шагу 2.

Самый тупой вариант на js для Хрома (в остальных браузерах не проверял - может не работать) получится как-то так:

```js
function parse(drivel) {
  drivel = drivel.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")
  var last = 0, back = false

  while(1) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(drivel)
    } catch (e) {
      var match = e.message.match(/^Unexpected token .*? in JSON at position (\d+)$/)
      if (!match) throw new Error("Failed to parse - unexpected error: " + e.message)
      var i = +match[1]

      if (i <= last) {
        if (back || last !== i+1) throw new Error(`Failed to parse - need to go back for fix: from ${last} to ${i} in ${JSON.stringify(drivel)}`)
        back = true
      } else {
        back = false
      }
      
      last = i
      drivel = drivel.slice(0, i-1) + "\\u" + (drivel[i].charCodeAt(0) + 0x10000).toString(16).slice(-4) + drivel.slice(i)
    }
  }
}

console.log(parse(`{"stat":"Сообщение успешно обработано","status":"OK","messageId":"123","messageResult":"Запрос обработан","messageDate":1558037969,"lastName":"Мяяя","firstName":"Vzzz","middleName":"Kkk","iin":"111222333444","birthdate":"16.11.1993","period":"6","table":[{"DATE_OPR":"2011-12-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"172755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"123","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123213","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-01-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"116755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-02-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-03-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"1231231232","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-04-01T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"117219.59999999998","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"111176.27599999998","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-05-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""}]}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Что в этом плохо?

1. Как я уже сказал, фикс не там, где он должен быть.
2. Вполне возможно, что могут быть данные, которые не удастся распознать правильно.
3. Этот код неэффективен:

   - он имеет квадратичную асимптотику, хотя то же самое можно сделать с линейной
   - он использует механизм исключений для неисключительных ситуаций
4. Этот код плох потому что

   - использует парсинг сообщения об ошибке не имея возможности другим способом получить позицию ошибкой - сообщение может меняться и код в таком случае перестанет работать; даже сейчас я не знаю, работает ли он где-то кроме хроме
   - возможно в нём есть другие недоработки со спецсимволами
5. Из плюсов

   - написанная функция всегда завершается - либо успешно, либо с исключением

Ну и если вдруг надо это переписывать на php, то пусть это останется задачей для автора.

Comment: `Исправлять надо там, откуда кривые данные приходят, а не там, где данные требуется использовать` угу, клиентам это объясните((

Comment: @DaemonHK, если это api, то клиент - это как раз автор вопроса ;)

Comment: @Qwerty забыл отписаться ) Спасибо за подробный ответ, это помогло тогда в решении. Помог такой колхоз str_replace('"', '&#34;', $q1);
                $q2 = json_decode($q1, true);    А формат формирования они так и не поменяли. Там ещё были проблемы с другими символами, но всё удалось решить после получения данных.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так может сойдет))

```
  <?php
    $date='{"stat":"Сообщение успешно обработано","status":"OK","messageId":"123","messageResult":"Запрос обработан","messageDate":1558037969,"lastName":"Мяяя","firstName":"Vzzz","middleName":"Kkk","iin":"111222333444","birthdate":"16.11.1993","period":"6","table":[{"DATE_OPR":"2011-12-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"172755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"123","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123213","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-01-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"116755.1","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"117000.03099999996","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-02-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-03-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"1231231232","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-04-01T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"117219.59999999998","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"111176.27599999998","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""},{"DATE_OPR":"2011-05-11T00:00:00+06:00","SUMM_DB":"115000.0","SUMM_DB_NETTO":"115578.4","PAY_ASSIGN":"","F52B_GUARANTOR_BANK_NAME":"АО "Verzi Bank" Обязат.пенсион.взносы GB (ГБ)","F50_GUARANTOR_RNN":"123123123","nameRu":""}]}';


    $gr=explode(':',$date);
    $chery=count($gr);

    for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) {

        $da2=explode(",", $gr[$i]);
    $da3=explode(",", $gr[$i+1]);

    $tu[$da2[1].'+'.$i]=$da3[0];


    }


    print_r($tu);
    ?>
```

Comment: Если уж городить, то тогда уж так `str_replace('АО "Verzi Bank"', 'АО \"Verzi Bank\"', $string)` и далее  `json_decode`

Comment: @РустамГимранов ага, а в другой выборке будет другой банк

Comment: Не надо такой код писать. Ничего хорошего из этого не получится.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ясное дело, что не надо огороды городить )))